# Regex for string between '>' sign

Tags: regex, python-2.7

If for example we have:

```
Inicio  >  Nacional y Política >  Protestas en Venezuela >  Nota
```

I want to retrieve just the string between the first and second '>'

This is a wild guess:

```
(?<!\w\>).+(?<!\>)
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty trivial task with basic string manipulation functions. Regex seems unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I didn't even think of that

Answer (score 0):

If you want in between the first and second `>` without whitespace, use [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/iV0xX1):

```
/(?:>\s+)(.*?)(?:\s>)/
```

This uses a non-capturing group for `>` followed by whitespace, a lazy capturing group with your string, and a non-capturing group for whitespace followed by `>`.  This means your string will be in the first match group.

If you don't care if there is extra whitespace in your string, you don't even need to use match groups and can use lookarounds like [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/rB8oJ2):

```
/(?<=>).*?(?=>)/
```

This looks behind for a `>`, then lazily matches everything up until the look ahead `>`.